# Parse error unexpected T_encapsed_and_whitespace, expected identifer t_string or variable t_variable , line 15

Tags: php

Not sure whats wrong with this line please help

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Official (name,description) VALUES ('{mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}' , '{mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Description'])} ')";
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your are supposing to do and error?

Comment: Maybe `mysqli` should have a `$` sign ?

Comment: [Variables parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) doesn't work this way. And it works only with variables, not with function/method calls, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simply your PHP syntax is wrong, should be as follow:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("server", "user", "password", "database");
    //---------------------
    // some other code here
    //---------------------
    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $desc = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Description']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Official (name, description) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$desc."')";
```